# Gridview footable with paging

Tags: c#, footable

I’m using Footable with a Gridview and the Footable paging.

When I leave the Gridview at a page, go to another page, and then hit "back" button of browser to come back, the page number was reset to "1".

Is it possible to remember the page number?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following javascript will retain page position.

```
function AttachjQueryFootableToTable() {
        $('[id*=GridView1]').footable({
            paging: {
                enabled: true,
                limit: 3,
                size: 10
            },
            state: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
    }
```